# How do I change the maximum and minimum element in the matrix row?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix

How do I change the maximum and minimum element in the matrix row?

Below I have given my code, it does not work correctly, the maximum and minimum elements in the lines are incorrectly swapped, the program is unstable.

```
number_of_rows = int(input("Enter the number of rows: ")) #matrix generator
m = [[int(j) for j in input("Enter all the elements of a single row (separated by a space): ").split()] for i in range(number_of_rows)]
print("Your matrix : ", *m, sep = '\n')

    for i, row in enumerate(m):
        max = min = 0
        for j, elem in enumerate(row):
            if elem > row[max]:
                max = j
            if elem < row[min]:
                min = j
        row[max], row[0] = row[0], row[max]
        row[min], row[-1] = row[-1], row[min]
    print(m)
```

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: `max` and `min` already mean something in Python. Best not to shadow these functions by declaring variables of the same name.

Comment: Should I delete the rows with the max and min substitutions for variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with comments from @Pranav Hosangadi regarding your use of min, and max for variables.  Here is how I would perform the matrix swap function:

```
for r, row in enumerate(m):
    mx_val = -float('inf')  #Sets max value to extremely low value to start
    mn_val = float('inf')   #Sets min_val to very high value to start
    mx_ptr = 0              # used to keep track of where in row max occurs
    mn_ptr = 0              #used to keep track of where min occurs
    for c, col in enumerate(row):           
        if col > mx_val:    #Test for col greater than current mx_val
            mx_ptr = c      # save the pointer
            mx_val = col    #save the value
        if col < mn_val:
            mn_ptr = c
            mn_val = col
    row[mn_ptr] = mx_val    #set row cell with mn_val to mx_val
    row[mx_ptr] = mn_val    #set row cell with mx_val to mn_val
print(m)
```

Comment: Thank you,@itprorh66